# Problems getting THEANO to work with GPU ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, neural-network, nvidia, theano

I have the following error when running:

```
CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

My bashrc file has ":/usr/local/cuda-7.5" at the end along with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64" at the end of it.

I suspect it has something to do with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about finding the library. The issue is that you have not upgraded your driver. Maybe it is not installed at all. Have you rebooted?

Check your driver version by using `nvidia-smi` or you can use `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`